# How best to handle m2m relationships within an API

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm busy creating an API using django with tastypie. I'm at a bit of a loss on how I should manage the foreign key relationship updates. I have User and Group objects related in a many-to-many fashion. Tastypie offers functionality for me to update the related set within each update, ie when I update a group I *must* supply the whole corresponding user set.

Ideally I'd like to have separate functionality to add and remove relationships. Consider the fact that 1 group has 1000 users, and I simply want to remove 2 users. I would love to access a url and give the 2 users that need to be deleted instead of loading the group object with its 1000 users, removing 2, then sending 998 users back along with the group details.

What is the correct design method to handle this case? Considering my use of tastypie, how can I best implement this practically?

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for? https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/72